# Ordenar array php por fechas

Tags: php, array

Hola que tal tengo un problema con un arreglo, al momento de generar la consulta me muestra las fechas desordenadas trato de ordenarlas con alguna funcion pero no lo consigo esto es lo que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como ven las fechas no siguen el orden correcto, este es el código:

```
$consulta = "SELECT EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP as NumEmpleado, concat(EMPLEADO.EMPAPEPAT,EMPLEADO.EMPAPEMAT,EMPLEADO.EMPNOM) as Nombre, format(Bitacora.Bitfecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as Fecha, format(MIN(Bitacora.Bitfecha),'HH:mm:ss tt') as Entrada, format(MAX(Bitacora.Bitfecha),'HH:mm:ss tt') as Salida, EMPRESA.EMPrDESC as Empresa
            FROM Bitacora
            INNER JOIN Empleado ON bitacora.Bitempnum = EMPLEADO.EMPNUMINT
            INNER JOIN EMPRESA ON Empresa.EMPrNUM = EMPLEADO.EMPrNUM
            WHERE cast(Bitacora.Bitfecha as date) between '$START_DATE' and '$END_DATE' and Empresa.EMPrDESC = '$SEMP'
            GROUP BY EMPLEADO.EMPNUMEMP, format(Bitacora.Bitfecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), concat(EMPLEADO.EMPAPEPAT,EMPLEADO.EMPAPEMAT,EMPLEADO.EMPNOM), EMPRESA.EMPrDESC
            ORDER BY EMPNUMEMP";

        $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta);
        $datos = array();
            while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar)){

                $num = $fila['NumEmpleado'];
                $nom = $fila['Nombre'];
                $fec = $fila['Fecha'];
                $ent = $fila['Entrada'];
                $sal = $fila['Salida'];

        $datos[] = array('NumEmpleado'=>$num, 'Nombre'=>$nom, 'Fecha'=>$fec, 'Entrada'=>$ent, 'Salida'=>$sal);

            }


            foreach ($datos as $arr){
                if(!$grupo[$arr['Fecha']]){
                    $grupo[$arr['Fecha']]=array();
                }
                $grupo[$arr['Fecha']] []=$arr['Entrada'];
                $grupo[$arr['Fecha']] []=$arr['Salida'];
                }
        arsort($arr);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($grupo);
        echo '</pre>';
```

Alguna idea del porque me hace eso.

Comment: Quizá esta web te ayude, hacen uso del método `usort()`: https://nideaderedes.urlansoft.com/2013/02/28/ordenar-un-array-por-fechas-en-php/

Comment: has probado haciedo el `ÒRDER BY fecha`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes cambiar el `ORDER BY EMPNUMEMP` por `ORDER By Bitacora.Bitfecha`, con esto no será necesario ordenar el arreglo, ni siquiera sería necesario traspasar los registros de la consulta a un arreglo, ya que los datos vendrán ordenados por el campo de fecha.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Cambie el `ORDER BY EMPNUMEMP` por `ORDER BY` Fecha o `ORDER BY Bitacora.Bitfecha`